# Separate threadPool for each task

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I've got application which has two main task: encoding, processing video.
These tasks are independant.
Each task I would like run with configurable number of threads. 
For this reason for one task I usually use ThreadPool and SetMaxThreads. But now I've got two tasks and would like "two configurable(number of threads) threapool for each task". 
Well, ThreadPool is a static class. So how can I implement my strategy(easy configurable number of threads for each task).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will probably want your own thread pool. If you are using .NET 4.0 then it is actually fairly easy to roll your own if you use the `BlockingCollection` class.

```
public class CustomThreadPool
{
  private BlockingCollection<Action> m_WorkItems = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

  public CustomThreadPool(int numberOfThreads)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
    {
      var thread = new Thread(
        () =>
        {
          while (true)
          {
            Action action = m_WorkItems.Take();
            action();
          }
        });
      thread.IsBackground = true;
      thread.Start();
    }
  }

  public void QueueUserWorkItem(Action action)
  {
    m_WorkItems.Add(action);
  }
}
```

That is really all there is to it. You would create a `CustomThreadPool` for each actual pool you want to control. I posted the minimum amount of code to get a crude thread pool going. Naturally, you might want to tweak and expand this implementation to suit your specific need.